# Showering with an antique shower

Tags: prepositions, spoken-english

A person loves antique showers (showerhead). So is the use of "with" natural in this context?.

> He loves showering with an antique shower. (Shower = Showerhead)

Is the use of "with" natural in this context?

Comment: So can't just "shower" be used to mean a "showerhead" @ColonD

Comment: @ColonD you could pluralise the noun but it's not essential. *He loves wearing a particular baseball cap* VS *He loves wearing baseball caps* In the OP's example, the antique in antique shower head makes it unique, not your usual bog-standard showerhead

Comment: @ColonD that's possible but it's not a certainty. Moreover, I'm not utterly convinced by the term "antique", maybe the OP is thinking of "old fashioned" or "vintage". How many showers actually have an "antique" shower-head? Today's [bathtubs](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1228&bih=647&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=dA_xXMfXPOai1fAPj6yzuAs&q=cast+iron+bathtubs+clawfoot&oq=cast+iron+bathtubs+clawfoot&gs_l=img.3...5354.11639..13114...0.0..0.75.545.8......0....1..gws-wiz-img.uJpyzd-tPJI) can imitate those  of yesteryear and also include a shower extension in the same "olde" style.

Comment: I did mean "old-fashioned" and "Vintage" indeed. @Mari-Lou A

Comment: @ColonD There is nothing wrong with saying *he loves showering with an antique shower head*, even if it's being used in a generalized sense. (*I love a hearty breakfast.*) It's entirely subjective which construction to use. It's not the case that you *should* pluralize it, simply that you *can* pluralize it. It's a matter of style, not grammar.